# how to use an external javascript file with visual studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010

I used the link to attach the js file but the aspx cant read functions from it.

Comment: it was a Firefox cache probelm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From within your *.aspx file you should write:

```
<script src="/script-location/your-script.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="http://www.yousite.com/script-location/your-script.js"></script>
```

You can then use functions from within it:

```
<script>
    mySpecialFunction();
</script>
```

[See It Here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/javascript/ht/htjsincludehtm.htm)